# How to define a function for a directed graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I was tasked with answering this question in my book:

> Let E be the set of edges in the directed graph below, and let V be the set of vertices. Define a function *h: E ---> V* as follows: For any edge *e ∈ E*, let *h(e)* be the vertex that edge *e* points at. Explain why this function is not onto. Be Specific.

I couldn't find a way to post a picture of the graph, so here are the in/out degrees:

> u: 2 in, 0 out
>
> v: 0 in, 3 out
>
> w: 1 in, 4 out
>
> x: 3 in, 0 out
>
> y: 1 in, 0 out
>
> z: 1 in, 1 out

My question here is how do I define this in a function? Like what symbols do I use to show that h(e) is the vertex that e points at? I don't understand how to put this on paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onto means that for every element of $v$, there is an edge that ends at vertex $v$. Can you find a vertex which doesn't have an edge pointing at it? (That is, a vertex with in-degree zero)

If so, then it isn't onto.

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't exactly what I was looking for. I was more looking for clarification on what they meant when they said "Define a function...".

Comment: They defined the function $h$ in the problem.

Comment: Oh, really? Well, I completely misunderstood the question then. Is that how functions are normally defined?

Comment: Yes, people often use words to define functions.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I thought they were asking for a function that has like mathematical symbols in it.